# installing querybuilder without visual studio

Tags: jquery, query-builder

I downloaded QueryBuilder from this site:

querybuilder.js.org/#installation

It says it depends on the following dependencies:

- jQuery >= 1.10
- Bootstrap >= 3.1 (CSS Buttons and Utilities only)
- $.extendext
- doT.js >= 1.0.3
- MomentJS (optional, for Date/Time validation)

So I downloaded all of those.

It also tells me to download and reference query-builder.css and query-builder.js. So I download them and reference them from index.html.

My folder now looks like this:

[my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dgyw.png)

I also included a folder for JQuery 1.11.1 and referenced it from index.html.

index.html looks like this:

```html
<html>
<head>

<link href="JQuery\jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="JQuery\jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="JQuery\jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery\jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery\jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="query-builder.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" href="query-builder.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="builder"></div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#builder').queryBuilder();
});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

But if you go to http://www.shahspace.com/querybuilder/index.html you see it's not working.

The download page reads like boostrap and other dependencies are supposed to be installed through visual studio. I'm just using an ordinary Notepad file.

Is there anything extra I need to do to set all this up correctly? What files in Bootstap, $.extendext, doT.js etc. do I need to reference?

Answer (score 1):

I run your code at http://www.shahspace.com/querybuilder/index.html.
l look into the console and read 
"Object doesn't support property or method 'queryBuilder'"

Then I check network-requests and can not see query-builder.js is loaded.

That is the probem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="query-builder.js"></script>
```

A script  do not have *href*.
Use *src* instead

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="query-builder.js"></script>
```